# evaluate two sums in analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

How should I evaluate the following sums

1, $\sum_{p\leq t}\frac{log^2(p)}{p}$

where the sum is taken over all prime numbers.

2, $\sum_{n\leq X}\frac{\Lambda^2(n)}{n}$

where $\Lambda(\cdot)$ is [the Mangoldt function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function)

---

RK: By evaluating, I mean to find an approximating formula as the following one

$\sum_{p\leq t}\frac{log(p)}{p}=log(t)+O(1)$

Comment: Since $\theta(x)\sim\psi(x)\sim x$ by the PNT, both $1$ and $2$ are $\log^2 t+O(\log t)$ by partial summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write using partial summation formula,

$\displaystyle \begin{align} \sum\limits_{p \le x} \dfrac{\log^2 p}{p} = \sum\limits_{p \le x} \log p\dfrac{\log p}{p} &= \log x\sum\limits_{p \le x} \dfrac{\log p}{p} - \int_2^{x} \frac{\sum\limits_{p \le t} \frac{\log p}{p}}{t}\,dt \\&= \log x(\log x + \mathcal{O}(1)) - \int_2^{x} \frac{\log t + \mathcal{O}(1)}{t}\,dt \\&= \frac{1}{2}\log^2 x + \mathcal{O}(\log x) \end{align}$

As for the second one you can use partial summation like the first one or see that,

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n \le x} \frac{\Lambda^2(n)}{n} \le  \sum\limits_{p \le x} \log^2 p\left(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}+\cdots\right) = \sum\limits_{p \le x} \dfrac{\log^2 p}{p} +\mathcal{O}\left(\sum\limits_{p} \dfrac{\log^2 p}{p^2}\right)$

Since, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{p} \dfrac{\log^2 p}{p^2}$ is a constant.

Thus, $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n \le x} \frac{\Lambda^2(n)}{n} = \sum\limits_{p \le x} \dfrac{\log^2 p}{p} +\mathcal{O}(1)$.